# Use helm sdk to use helm template command

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We need to switch the following command for code using helm sdk,
`helm template .`

I tried the following and it doesnt works/complie, what am I missing here?

https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/cmd/helm/template.go

```
import (
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm"
)




func main(){

    templateCommand, err := helm.NewTemplateCmd(append([]string{chartName}, args...))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Helm version `3.7.1`

Comment: Which helm version are you using (`helm version` command)?

Comment: @MikolajS.  we are using helm 3.7.1

Comment: is that all your current go-code? if so it should not compile because you assign 'templateCommand' but do nothing with it at the moment.

Comment: The [Helm documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#go-sdk) suggests using [`helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action`](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action), though this doesn't contain any direct way to render the template.  That logic is in `.../pkg/engine` but requires you to come up with a `*chart.Chart` first.  I don't have a working example off hand unfortunately.